# aws ec2 not serving static files in a django react application

Tags: python, reactjs, django, amazon-web-services, django-react

I am trying to deploy a django react ecommerce app using aws ec2. when i run python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 it is loading the page but not serving static files. The errors are

```
[24/Jun/2021 19:29:26] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2297
[24/Jun/2021 19:29:26] "GET /static/css/2.97503911.chunk.css HTTP/1.1" 404 179
[24/Jun/2021 19:29:26] "GET /static/css/main.4586955f.chunk.css HTTP/1.1" 404 179
[24/Jun/2021 19:29:26] "GET /static/js/2.7e7fd32c.chunk.js HTTP/1.1" 404 179
[24/Jun/2021 19:29:26] "GET /static/js/main.002fbd2b.chunk.js HTTP/1.1" 404 179
```

Here is my settings.py file

```
"""
Django settings for backend project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
from datetime import timedelta

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '+^5qu3r54+4ja6q(_$rc!w4*z9t$erk61j=m8wbry53y*c-&h*'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ['http://localhost:3000']

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['myamazonclone.ml']

SITE_ID = 1

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'corsheaders',
    'dj_rest_auth',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'dj_rest_auth.registration',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist',
    'users',
    'payment',
    'products',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny'
    ],

    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        'dj_rest_auth.jwt_auth.JWTCookieAuthentication',
        # 'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        # 'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    )

}

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=60),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': True,
    'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': True,
    'UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN': False,

    'ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    # 'SIGNING_KEY': settings.SECRET_KEY,
    'VERIFYING_KEY': None,
    'AUDIENCE': None,
    'ISSUER': None,

    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer', 'JWT'),
    'AUTH_HEADER_NAME': 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION',
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'id',
    'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'user_id',

    'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',),
    'TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM': 'token_type',

    'JTI_CLAIM': 'jti',

    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_EXP_CLAIM': 'refresh_exp',
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=60),
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
}

REST_USE_JWT = True

JWT_AUTH_COOKIE = 'my-app-auth'
JWT_AUTH_REFRESH_COOKIE = 'users-refresh-token'

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'backend.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR/'frontend'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'backend.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR/'static'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR/'frontend/static']

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False

# E-mail address is automatically confirmed by a GET request
ACCOUNT_CONFIRM_EMAIL_ON_GET = True
# Allow logins with an unverified e-mail address
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'none'

# REST_AUTH_REGISTER_SERIALIZERS = {
#     'REGISTER_SERIALIZER': 'users.serializers.CustomRegistrationSerializer'
# }

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
]
```

I have mentioned the STATIC_ROOT above and have also done python manage.py collectstatic. After doing so it makes a static folder in the root where manage.py is located and it also contains all the files the django is unable to find and gives 404. I also tried using gunicorn but still it is not able to serve static files. I donot understand what mistake i am making . Any help will be really appriciated.
Here is my file structure

```
Amazon Prod
├─ backend
│  ├─ asgi.py
│  ├─ settings.py
│  ├─ urls.py
│  ├─ wsgi.py
│  ├─ __init__.py
│  └─ __pycache__
│     ├─ settings.cpython-39.pyc
│     ├─ urls.cpython-39.pyc
│     ├─ wsgi.cpython-39.pyc
│     └─ __init__.cpython-39.pyc
├─ db.sqlite3
├─ frontend
│  ├─ asset-manifest.json
│  ├─ favicon.ico
│  ├─ index.html
│  ├─ logo192.png
│  ├─ logo512.png
│  ├─ manifest.json
│  ├─ robots.txt
│  └─ static
│     ├─ css
│     │  ├─ 2.97503911.chunk.css
│     │  ├─ 2.97503911.chunk.css.map
│     │  ├─ main.4586955f.chunk.css
│     │  └─ main.4586955f.chunk.css.map
│     └─ js
│        ├─ 2.7e7fd32c.chunk.js
│        ├─ 2.7e7fd32c.chunk.js.LICENSE.txt
│        ├─ 2.7e7fd32c.chunk.js.map
│        ├─ main.002fbd2b.chunk.js
│        ├─ main.002fbd2b.chunk.js.map
│        ├─ runtime-main.e2a9cdff.js
│        └─ runtime-main.e2a9cdff.js.map
├─ manage.py
├─ payment
├─ products
├─ requirements.txt
├─ static
└─ users
```

backend is the name of project. frontend is the production build react app.

here is my project urls.py file

```
from django import urls
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import (
    TokenObtainPairView,
    TokenRefreshView,
)
from users.views import BlacklistTokenUpdateView

# Allows to render a template without a view
from django.views.generic import TemplateView


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    path('dj-rest-auth/', include('dj_rest_auth.urls')),
    path('dj-rest-auth/registration/', include('dj_rest_auth.registration.urls')),
    path('api/token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('api/token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
    path('blacklist/', BlacklistTokenUpdateView.as_view(), name='blacklist'),
    path('payment/', include('payment.urls')),
    path('storeApi/', include('products.urls')),
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the ownership of the files. If you load your files as ec_user and try to deliver as www-data with 640 permissions you will have 404s.
wild bet.